# Turing machine ends when input is like 000111

Tags: turing-machines

we have a tape of random 0s and 1s, how do design a turning machine that ends when the input is like #000111#, where numbers of 0 and 1 are equal.

homework. First time posting a question, thank you!

Comment: Do the 0s and 1s have to be together?

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need Turing machines for this ....

Without giving away too much this equivalent to the context free grammar

```
A => BC

B => B | 0B | 1B | empty

C => 01 | 0C1
```

So all you really need is a stack (which is really easy to implement with more than 2 tapes or some interesting management of 1 tape).